# Pandas Dataframe - How to check if the dates are less than 30 days from now

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to create a column that identifies if the dates are less than 30 days from now (with boolean values). Here is the sample:

```
data={'Process_ID':['12345-98', '23547-75', '85763-99','44231-56','78456-00','53218-87'],
     'Date': ['2021-06-30','2022-08-10','2021-06-15','2023-10-02','2024-04-03','2021-06-25']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

print(df)
```

The dataframe is the following:

```
    Process_ID  Date
0   12345-98    2021-06-30
1   23547-75    2022-08-10
2   85763-99    2021-06-15
3   44231-56    2023-10-02
4   78456-00    2024-04-03
5   53218-87    2021-06-25
```

Considering this table, how can I check if these dates are less than 30 days from now? Please, take into account that past dates like 15-06-2021 (dd/mm/yyyy) should not be registered as True. I just want future dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
df['new'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: True if 
    (x - pd.Timestamp.now() < pd.Timedelta('30 days')) 
    and x > pd.Timestamp.now() else False)
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it identifies dates that are in the past (e.g. 15-06-2021 in dd/mm/yyyy format) as True. However, they are not 30 days from now, because they are in the past. Do you know how could I solve it? Thank you very much.

Comment: so you want both 30 days in the past and 30 days in the future or just 30 days in the future and no past?

Comment: Just 30 days in the future and no past. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Update per comment:

```
df.assign(dif = (df['Date'] - pd.Timestamp("now")).dt.days).eval('0 < dif < 30')
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```

Try:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
(df['Date'] - pd.Timestamp('now')).lt(pd.Timedelta(days=30))
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
Name: Date, dtype: bool
```

Comment: It worked! The only thing I would add is the following: df['Warning']=(df['Date'] - pd.Timestamp('now')).lt(pd.Timedelta(days=30)). This will create a new column in the dataframe indicating the boolean values. Thank you very much!

Comment: what ".lt" means? I did not find it in the documentation

Comment: here it is: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html

Comment: @ Scott Boston The problem with this solution is that it identifies dates that are in the past (e.g. 15-06-2021 in dd/mm/yyyy format) as True. However, they are not 30 days from now, because they are in the past. Do you know how could I solve it? Thank you very much.